# Stray cat terrorized because of medicines and trust issues

Tags: cats, behavior, veterinarian, strays

I'm Dex from India.
I have been feeding a stray cat (1 year old male) near my house for almost 3-4 months. A week ago or so he has got some minor skin issues after fight with another stray cat (happened 12-15 days ago approx.). He was and is eating cat food and drinking water and playing normally. I contacted an NGO & their vet has prescribed me 2 liquid medicines and one cream (amoxicillin and cetrizine and the cream is Betnovate N). I can't bring him home b/c of family and apartment issues. After giving him the first 2 doses he is extremely terrorized and is kind of scared of me. He is constantly suspicious of my movements and is hesitating to even come near me. If I try to get near him on my own he runs below the parked cars nearby and doesn't come out fast. I had to wait for 10-15 mins and then he came next to me. If I give him the medicines again, I think he might stop trusting me completely. I'm worried if I continue with the medications it will break his trust. Can there be any adverse effects if I stop the medications? Applying Betnovate N cream is not an issue but giving him the liquid medicines is proving to be very difficult.
Exams are round the corner and I'm too worried about what I should do. Please someone who has experience with cats or is a vet guide me.

Edit 1 -
For the 1st dose, I called him on a platform nearby and then when I positioned him and tried to open his mouth, he started resisting and moving. As he opened the mouth, I squirted the liquid medicine in his mouth using a syringe and he sprang up with full strength and ran below the parked car.
Everyday I give him food on the ground in a flat lunchbox, so maybe the platform was a bit suspicious for him. Also, till now I have been only seeing him once in a day that is to give him food and some pets and cuddles. For the 2nd dose, he didn't come on his own. So I lured him using catfood and then I gave him the medicine. Now, I think he has slightly associated me with the medicine and probably that's why he runs immediately if I try to lift him.

Comment: This sounds like the way you gave him the liquid medicine scared him. Can you please explain how you gave him this medicine? Did you hold him down or did you have to force him? Please [edit] your question to add more information **why** he avoids you.

Comment: @elmy check edit. thank you!